# Помогите решить проблему с Resource Root в IDEA!

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Всем добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, при создании игры Сапер на Java, я делаю путь к папке с картинками через getClass.get.Resource() и папка в которой лежат изображения, отмечаю ее Resource Root. После запуска все работает но не показывает изображения в окне к которым указан путь. Данный вопрос поднимался на сайте и его решение было просто поставить слеш перед **"/img/"** - но данное решение не помогло в моем случае.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaSweeper extends JFrame {

private JPanel panel; 
private final int COLS = 15;
private final int ROWS = 1;
private final int IMAGE_SIZE = 50;

public static void main(String[] args) {
new JavaSweeper();
}

private JavaSweeper() {
initPanel();
initFrame();
}

private void initPanel() {
panel = new JPanel() {
@Override
protected void printComponent (Graphics g) {
super.printComponent(g);
g.drawImage(getImage("bomb"), 0, 0, this);
}
};

panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(COLS * IMAGE_SIZE, ROWS * IMAGE_SIZE));/
add(panel);
}

private void initFrame() {
pack();
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("JavaSweeper");
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setResizable(false);
setVisible(true);
}

private Image getImage(String name) {// метод получения картинки
String fileName = "img/" + name.toLowerCase() + ".png";//определить картинку
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource(fileName));
return icon.getImage();// возвращаем картинку
}

}
```

Comment: Покажите дерево каталогов вашего проекта и собственно сам *Resource Root* и в конце-то концов отформатируйте код с правильным `indentation`

Comment: картинки должны (стандартно) иметь такой же путь относительно корня (ресурсной директории, стандартно она называется resources), какой имеют классы, относительно корневой директории исходников (java), тогда при сборке class-файлы и файлы ресурсов, оказываются в одной директории и, соответственно, getClass().getResource(filename) - класс видит filename как файл рядом (поэтому дополнительно никакого пути к файлу не приписывается)